how to make helm hook job exit when it run fail
I use this yaml to my charts
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "createmysql-hook"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded,before-hook-creation
spec:
  backoffLimit: 1
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: precheck
        image: busybox:1.32
        command: ['/bin/sh']
        args:
        - -c
        - |
          echo "准备创建 mysql 账户,账户名称: {{ .Chart.Name }}"
          accountName="{{ .Chart.Name }}"
          wget -O res "http://172.17.0.1:30503/free/device/getNodeCode/$accountName"
          res=$(cat res)
          if [ "$res" = "success" ]; then
            echo "账户创建成功"
            exit 0
          else
            echo "账户创建失败,错误信息:$res"
            exit 1
          fi

then use helm Request to creat deployment
the shell in busybox while nevet success
so i think this job while run once and exit
but when i see event it's always retry
like this
res
so i think maybe retry police is set for pod,not job
but i don't know how to make job just run once
thanks
I try to set backofflimit and restartpolicy but not use

Yes, the backoffLimit and restartPolicy settings are meant for pods/deployments only it won't work with Jobs.
In your case, it's restarting because it's failing to do the task defined in the script. Please check if the script is functioning as expected.
